# Prolog: aStar method for maximization (how to use estimative??)

Tags: prolog, a-star

i have a problem with the aStar method for maximization, the goal is with this method find the strongest path

This is the knowledge base

```
no/3 (First value is the id of a user, the rest doesn't matter for the problem context)

no(1,_,_).
no(11,_,_). 
no(12,_,_).
no(21,_,_).
no(22,_,_).     
...

connection/4 (1 value: user id, 2 value: user friend id, 3 value: bond strength, 4 value: relationship strength)

connection(1,12,2,6).
connection(1,13,-3,-2).
connection(1,14,1,-5).
connection(11,21,5,7).
connection(11,22,2,-4).
...
connection(21,32,-2,3).
connection(21,33,3,5).
connection(21,34,4,2).
connection(22,31,5,-4).
connection(22,32,-1,6).
...
```

The exemple i give is a aStar method but for minimixation (and not in the context problem)

```
aStar(Orig,Dest,Cam,Cust):- aStar2(Dest,[(_,0,[Orig])],Cam,Cust).

aStar2(Dest,[(_,Cust,[Dest|T])|_],Cam,Custo):-reverse([Dest|T],Cam).

aStar2(Dest,[(_,Ca,LA)|Outros],Cam,Cust):-LA=[Act|_],
findall((CEX,CaX,[X|LA]),(Dest\==Act,edge(Act,X,CustX),\+ member(X,LA),
CaX is CustX + Ca, estimative(X,Dest,EstX),CEX is CaX +EstX),Novos),
append(Outros,Novos,Todos),sort(Todos,AllSorted),aStar2(Dest,AllSorted,Cam,Cust).

estimative(Nodo1,Nodo2,Estimativa):-
node(Nodo1,Nodo2,X1,Y1),
node(Nodo2,Nodo1,X2,Y2),
Estimativa is sqrt((X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2).
```

My problem is how to use the estimative method in a social graph

I have this suggestions that might help:

> • In a social network, the concept of geometric distance does not exist.
> We will have to calculate the Estimate in another way.
> • It is suggested that they have an estimate of the maximum strength they will have
> from the node of the A* tree you are considering to the solution.
> • Note that if the threshold level is N and the node we have is at level M
> (consider the root of the A* tree to level 0) then at most
> we can by this node of the tree advance N-M levels
> In a first approach as strength has a maximum value of 100,
> we can say that the estimate (an upper bound in the case in question) would have the value 100*(N-M)
> • If an estimate that is an upper bound is desirable, the ideal is to have it as close as the real value that we will have along a given path in the tree. This would be an excess bound and when using it we will have an effect that will be similar to the conversion of the A* in the Branch&Bound method when in the minimization problems the estimate was equal to 0
> • A better solution is to see all the separate network strengths they have created and get the maximum binding strength value. For example if this value is 20 then we can use 20*(N-M)
> • A better solution is to create a list with all the strengths of the links up to order N and order it in descending order without removing repeats (which we have already mentioned). Then we remove the forces that were used from the root node to the candidate node for expansion in the A* tree and if M levels are missing then we take the first M elements from that list. In fact we can't have more than that, it would be all the biggest values ​​to be aligned in the path that we will go from the node in question of the A* tree

Any help is always welcome and I apologize for the long text for my problem.

Comment: This is too much to read and process. The strange grammar is not helping.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edit now my problem, is in how calculate the estimative with one value (connection/4  with the third value)